# Zapier Trigger: Remove "Other options" from dynamic dropdown

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'd like to remove the "other options" in the dynamic dropdown (and remove the ID of the available options). How can i do that?

[image: other options in dynamic dropdown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That's not possible to remove at this time. It's important in actions so that users can provide the field value dynamically from a previous step (instead of selecting one at creation time).

Thanks for asking!